# How do I apply a Butterworth filter using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have a set of data I want to filter. I've tried using the 'butter' command as such:

```
[B,A]=butter(2,0.125)
```

followed by

```
newOut=filter(B,A,input)
```

The problem is that every filtered data point becomes `NaN`.

I found a very nice demonstration here:

[Filtering MATLAB Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wmFPQcBiE4)

It seems to be a successful way to implement a Butterworth filter, but whenever I try to do one, my filtered matrix is just a string of `NaN`'s.

Any ideas on why this might be happening or how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Does your input vector contain any `NaN`? If you do `all(isfinite(input))` it should return 1.

Comment: No I took all NaN out before filtering